# Incorrect mapping for length attribute in JPA @Column

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, oracle11g, hibernate-mapping

I'm using Hibernate 4.0.0.Final as the JPA persistence provider for an application, with an Oracle 11g database (created with UTF-8 encoding) and Oracle WebLogic 11g as the application server. The dialect configured in `persistence.xml` is `org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect`.

In my Entities, I'm mapping String fields like this:

```
@Column(length=20)
private String description;
```

I'm letting JPA handle the creation of the tables in the database. To my surprise, in the database the column definition for the previous field looks like this:

```
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(80 BYTE)
```

When I insert a value in the `description` field (using an SQL console, not from the application), I can insert up to 80 characters, not the 20 that I'd have expected.

What's the problem here? I guess that the column  definition is created with 80 bytes for allowing the storage of UTF-8 characters, but it messes with the expected maximum length of the field at the database level. Ideally, I would want the field to look like this:

```
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
```

But I don't know how to configure Hibernate for mapping a string field with `CHAR` and not `BYTE`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that I was using as dialect `org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect` caused the problem. I dug into the source code, and this line appears in the `OracleDialect` class:

```
registerColumnType( Types.VARCHAR, 4000, "varchar2($l)" );
```

Actually, this was a known [issue](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-898). By default, Oracle generates `varchar2($l byte)` for the previous definition. If I switch to `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`, the recommended dialect for Oracle 11g, the previous line ends up looking like this:

```
registerColumnType( Types.VARCHAR, 4000, "varchar2($l char)" );
```

Now the correct definition gets generated (using `char` instead of `byte`), and that solves my problem.

Comment: Hi Oscar, I am also facing the same problem. I understood that OracleDialect will by default create byte type but how did the size of the column increase from 20 to 80? it should have been 20 bytes right?

Comment: 20 chars == 80 bytes, each char is taking 4 bytes